# Twilio stop recording of a call

Tags: twilio

We are currently developing an autodialler using twilio - we are using conferences. The call center operator will be sitting in a conference room and then calls are initiated via twilios rest api and then moved into the conference. We are not wanting to record the entire conference but just the calls within the conference. We will be transferring calls as part of this but when we transfer to a third party we want to ensure this isn't recorded. Is there a way to stop recording with Twilio.

Comment: How are you transferring to a third party?

Comment: we trigger an api method we have created that initiates a new call and puts the third party in the conference once they have successfully answered the call.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There isn't an API native way to stop the recording of a conference part way through. What I'd recommend here is that, when you want to initiate the call to the third party to bring them into the conference, also initiate a couple of requests the [use the Twilio API to redirect the current calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) into a new, non-recording conference and direct the third party into that conference instead.

Let me know if that helps at all.